# C program linking with shared library without setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

I was reading Introduction to GCC and it says if a package has both .a and .so. gcc prefer the shared library. By default the loader searches for shared libraries only in a predefined set of system directories, such as `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib`. If the library is not located in one of these directories it must be added to the load path, or you need to use `-static` option to force it to use the .a library. However, I tried the following:

vim hello.c:

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        mpz_t x;
        mpz_init(x);
        return 0;
}

gcc hello.c -I/opt/include -L/opt/lib -lgmp  (my gmp library is in opt)
./a.out
```

And it runs. The book says it should have the following error:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries:
libgdbm.so.3: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory
```

(well, the book uses GDBM as example but I used GMP, but this won't matter right?)

However, I did not set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/lib`, and as you can see I did not use `-static` option either, but `a.out` still runs.

Can you all tell me why and show me how to get the error described in the book? Yes I want the error so I will understand what I misunderstood.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that there is no `libgmp` in `/usr/lib`? Also, make sure that there is no entry for `/opt/lib` in `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Comment: Also, make sure that your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set for you.  Unset it with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` (nothing after the `=`).

Comment: I used echo LD_LIBRARY_PATH to verify already it is empty. Thank you! Besides, I did install the library under /usr/local before (as a way to study), but I have already deleted them all already and installed again to /opt/. Thanks everyone for your kind help

Comment: What does the output of `ldd` on your `a.out` look like?

Comment: linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7746000)
 libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0xb76c5000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7520000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7747000)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your response to my comment:

```
linux-gate.so.1 => (0xb7746000)
libgmp.so.10 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10 (0xb76c5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7520000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7747000)
```

So, your program is picking up the lib from `/usr/lib`.

What you can try to do is rename the lib in your `/opt/lib`, and link against the new name.

```
mv /opt/lib/libgmp.so /opt/lib/libgmp-test.so
gcc hello.c -I/opt/include -L/opt/lib -lgmp-test
```

Then try running the program. Also, compare the result of `ldd` against the new `a.out` against what you got before.

Comment: Alright.. Thank you. But could you show me how to let it pick up the library from /opt/ instead of /usr/lib? This is really confusing to me because in the GMP documentation it says if you do "make install" it will be install to /usr/local/lib but I did "make install -prefix=/opt", and now it is picking up the library from /usr/lib...

Comment: I renamed it to libgmpt.so and then I did "gcc hello.c -I/opt/include -L/opt/lib -lgmpt". But it is still picking up from /usr/lib/ and a.out still runs without error. Well I think I spent too much time trying to understand this already. I don't know. Maybe I should just keep on reading and put this aside?

Comment: @ZesenHuang: What does your `ldd` on `a.out` say now?

Comment: I tried gmp_randinit_default and gmp_randseed_ui already. Same story. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: @ZesenHuang: Thanks for accepting my answer, +1 on your question.