# What is the point of using `-L` when there is `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385331/c-program-linking-with-shared-library-without-setting-ld-library-path/11385376#comment15006786_11385376), my first reaction was that the user is not seeing the error because he specifies the location of the library with `-L`.

However, apparently, the `-L` option only influences where the linker looks, and has no influence over where the loader looks when you try to run the compiled application.

My question then is what's the point of `-L`? Since you won't be able to run your binary unless you have the proper directories in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` anyway, why not just put them there in the first place, and drop the `-L`, since the linker looks in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` automatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be the case that you are cross-compiling and the linker is targeting a system other than your own. For instance, MinGW can be used to compile Windows binaries on Linux. Here `-L` will point to the DLLs needed for linking and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will point to any libraries needed by linker to run. This allows compiling and linking of different architectures, OS ABIs, or processor types.

It's also helpful when trying to build special targets. I might be case that one links a static version of program against a different static library. This is the first step in Linux From Scratch, where one creates a separate mini-environment on the main system to become a `chroot` jail.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will affect all the commands you run to build your code (including the compiler itself).

That's not desirable in general (e.g. you might not want your compiler to run debug/instrumented libraries while it compiles - it might even go as far as breaking your compiles).

Use `-L` to tell the compiler where to look, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to influence runtime linking.

Answer (score 3):

*Building* the binary and *running* the binary are two completely independent and unrelated processes. You seem to suggest that the running environment should affect the building environment, i.e. you seem to be making an assumption that the code build in some setup (account, machine) will be later run in the same setup. I find this assumption rather strange.   I'd even say that in most cases the building and the running are done in different environments. I would actually prefer my compilers not to derive any assumptions about future running environment from the environment these compilers are invoked in. Looking onto the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` of the building environment would be a major no-no.

Comment: In the vast majority of cases, you will build your program, and then you'll want to test it on your own machine (obviously you might ship it to others later, but you'll still usually test it on your machine first). Therefore you'll have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` accordingly. So using `-L` would be redundant, no?

Comment: @houbysoft LD_LIBRARY_PATH also affect the runtime of your compiler any any other tool you use to build the binary. You want to keep your build environment pristine and homogeneous, and rather vary arguments to the compiler. Also, LD_LIBRARY_PATH can't be used for static libraries.

Comment: @houbysoft: I do test my binaries on "my own machine" before shipping, but that's certainly not the machine that did the building or, at least, not the same environment that was used for building. In fact, I consider using the same environment for building and testing a major error for more reasons than one.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers are all good, but one nobody has mentioned yet is static libraries. Most of the time when you use `-L` it's with a static library built locally in your build tree that you don't intent to install, and it has nothing to do with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers on Solaris support the `-R /runtime/path/to/some/libs` that adds to the path where libraries are to be searched by the run-time linker. On Linux the same could be achieved with `-Wl,-rpath,/runtime/path/to/some/libs`. It passes the `-rpath /runtime/path/to/some/libs` option to `ld`. GNU `ld` also supports the `-R /path/to/libs` for compatibility with other ELF linkers but this should be avoided as `-R` is normally used to specify symbol files to GNU `ld`.